# Android: Multiple images in the same layout

Tags: android

I am designing a simple numbers flashcard screen for my 2 year old. The layout is simple with a titleheader, an Image (flashcard say 1).
When i click on the image (or anywhere on screen), it should go to the next image (flashcard 2) and so on till 10.
My question - do i need to defined 10 layouts? 10 activities?
New to android coding - appreciate any help.

```
public void numberClick(View v) {   
        ImageView portrait = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberImage);

        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.drawable.numberone:
                portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.numbertwo);

            case R.drawable.numbertwo:
                portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.numberthree);


        }
```

Updated code

```
public class numberActivity extends Activity {

ImageView portrait;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.number);

portrait = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberImage);

}

public void numberClick(View v) {   
    switch(v.getId()){
            case R.drawable.numberone:
                portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.numbertwo);
                break;

            case R.drawable.numbertwo:
                portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.numberthree);
                break;

        }

}
```

}

But the result is still not there - the images dont toggle.

Updated code with listener

```
public class numberActivity extends Activity {

ImageView portrait;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.number);

portrait = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberImage);

portrait.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.drawable.numberone:
                portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.numbertwo);
                break;

            case R.drawable.numbertwo:
                portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.numberthree);
                break;

        }

}});
}}
```

Comment: see viewSwitcher or viewPager

Answer (score 1):

You can have one activity with simple layout with one imageview. On click just set new image for this imageview.

Comment: Yes if you want only the images to change and not the layouts

Comment: and i am assuming that can be done for 10 images in the same activity? I have the code for 2 image changes. private boolean fuzzyImage = false; public void flipImage(View v) { ImageView portrait = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.faceImageView); if (fuzzyImage) { portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.clear_einstein); } else { portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.fuzzy_einstein); } fuzzyImage = !fuzzyImage; // flip the state for next time }    ;;; but i was not sure how to extrapolate this to 10 images.

Comment: create list/array of image ids and store current position.
int[] images = {R.drawable.clear_einstein,R.drawable.fuzzy_einstein.... }
int displaying =0; 
create next method:  
private void next(){
portrait.setImageResource(images[displaying++])
}

Answer (score 0):

Jasma first of all I appreciate your cause. In Android there are two possibilities of doing this.

1. Using Intents and activities.
2. Using the modern way(The fragments)

These are the possibilities for creating new layouts on user interaction. You can have any number of fragments and Activities you want. You can read more on this here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html and here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: @jasma you can use switch case in your context.

Comment: What am i doing wrong here? I am getting no errors while running, but nothing happens on click. 'public void numberClick(View v) { 
      ImageView portrait = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberImage);
 
      switch(v.getId()){
       case R.drawable.numberone:
        portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.numbertwo);
       
       case R.drawable.numbertwo:
        portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.numberthree);
       
       
      }'

Comment: You don't have "break" in your switch case. It is going to work for sure if you put a break statement. Accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: i have updated code. It gives me NO error, but image doesnt toggle as well. :(. Any advice?

Comment: where is the onclicklistener of your ImageView. Use an onlcik listener for you imageview and put the switch clause in it.

Comment: i did that as well. But it still wont toggle. Please see updated code.

Comment: check what is the View element returning each time and also first set the image background to null to first and then set it to whatever image required.